# Rails number_field tag placeholder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a number_field tag as follow:

```
<%= number_field :average_border, nil, min: 1, max: 4, :step => 'any', class: "number" %>
```

This number_filed tag is meant to be updated as pleased by the user with a number from 1 to 4.

I would like this tag to display the current value as a placeholder would do in a text field tag.

Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass `placeholder` attribute into it. But make sure you use the correct `form helpers`

if you are using `form_tag`

```
<%= number_field_tag :average_border, @current_value, min: 1, max: 4, :step => 'any', class: "number", placeholder: @hint_value %>
```

if you are using `form_for`

```
<%= f.number_field :average_border, min: 1, max: 4, :step => 'any', class: "number", placeholder: hint_value %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more thing: Do you have an idea why with my code I manage to save float number whereas with your solution it does not let me ?

Comment: What is the column type of `average_border` in database (int, float or something else)?

Comment: please put this in your controller `p params[:average_border]` and check the value in `logs console`

Comment: There should not be any problem with the form. Please check your controller, database column type, or may be your model.

Comment: Sorry My bad I found my problem. Thanks a lot !